# Implicit MySQL Join on Update Statement - 0 rows affected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I'm trying to get this **MySQL** code to work, but it's saying 0 rows affected.

```
UPDATE assessments, assessment_types
SET assessments.assessment_type_id = assessment_types.id
WHERE (assessment_types.description = "Skills Assessment" AND assessments.id = 2);
```

Basically I have **assessment_types** with **id** and **description** column, and I just have the **id** in the **assessments.assessment_type_id**

I need to update the **id**.

I searched and couldn't find quite what I need for this.

Thanks!

Table Data:
    **assessment_types**
    id  description
    1   Knowledge Assessment
    2   Skill Assessment
    3   Personal Information
    4   Natural Skills

Table Structure:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `assessments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `acronym` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `assessment_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_updated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `assessment_type_id` (`assessment_type_id`),
  KEY `language_id` (`language_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2385 ;
```

---

```
--
-- Table structure for table `assessment_types`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assessment_types` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

Comment: post your related table structure code please.

Comment: Specifically, tell us how to do an _explicit_ join between the two tables.

Comment: Please post the `create table code` of `assessments` and `assessment_types` table. @Kell

Comment: I guess `assessment_types.id` is the **PRIMARY** key. Then try this query `UPDATE assessments
SET assessments.assessment_type_id = (SELECT assessment_types.id FROM assessment_types WHERE assessment_types.description="Skills Assessment")
WHERE assessments.id = 2;`

Comment: This worked! Thank you

Comment: Can `Skills Assessment` occur multiple times in `assessment_types` table?

Comment: It worked, thanks so much!

Comment: It worked because `SELECT assessment_types.id FROM assessment_types WHERE assessment_types.description="Skills Assessment"` this query returned one row. If it would have returned more than one row then this would fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing an explicit join of the two tables in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE assessments a
INNER JOIN assessment_types at
    ON a.assessment_type_id = at.id
SET a.assessment_type_id = at.id
WHERE (at.description = "Skills Assessment" AND a.id = 2);
```

Comment: This gave 0 rows affected, however Subrata Dey Pappu's answer worked.

Comment: your matching and updating criteria is same..How can you expect query to update desire result?